# ¿como entro a modo super usuario en una disitrbucion de linux basado en fedora (ADIOS)?

Tags: linux, fedora

bueno... he estado buscando y lamentablemente no hay mucho para ver de la distribucion linux ADIOS
No se si alguien lo conoce o se da una idea de como usarlo, es la distribucion con la que trabaja mi docente y el problema esta en que cuando quiero cambiar a modo super usuario, me pide contraseña y no se como hacerlo, ya trate con "su" con "sudo" "sudo passwd root" pero en cualquier caso me pide una contraseña, al parecer viene bloqueado y no se como hacerlo... si se preguntan porque usamos esta distribucion pues solo nos dijo porque viene con un paquete o no se que instalado llamado "gcc"
Bueno eso es todo, solo quiero ver que formas hay para poder entrar a modo super usuario, aun si no estan familiarizados con esta distribucion, les agradeceria que me dijeran las formas que conocen para poder entrar, ya que tratare todas las que sea necesarias... ayudaaaa!!!

Answer (score 0):

Arranca con el usb/dvd de la distribución en modo recuperación.
Edita el fichero /etc/shadow

```
root:$6$OrqRmooe$2XSkIJNgd3Te/xPUd6S1wcysNgPhFfT7UFHkbmvjECkt/L9Z3rmqBUbRDBcfLf4sz/Z775X.WgJTaijVG7mhn1:15754:0:99999:7:::
```

deberá quedar asi:

```
root::15754:0:99999:7:::
```

En el siguiente arranque no te pedirá la password al pasarte a root.

No te olvides ponerle password a root.

```
passwd root
```